# VBA how to read heading style enumeration?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code that loops through the paragraphs of a document, and reapplies the heading style. This is in order to fix the numbering inconsistency after copy-pasting headings from different documents.

In my file I just have the following example:

```
For Each p In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
    If p.Style = "Heading 1" Then
        p.Style = "Heading 1"
    End If
Next p
```

This solves the issue, but the problem is if somebody has Word running in a different language, "Heading 1" is not applicable anymore. I tried with `wdstyleheading1` as well, but the `p.Style` always reads out the actual name of the style, not an enumeration.

I thought of `p.Style.ListLevelNumber`, but that seems to be too vague, and might mess up other lists in the document.

Is there a way to read or reference it in a language independent way?
Is there perhaps a better solution altogether for the numbering problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the local name for a style with .NameLocal. It's kind of a workaround because I don't think you can actually compare a paragraphs .Style with the enum, but this should do the trick.

```
For Each p In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
    If p.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal Then
        p.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    End If
Next p
```

Comment: `.NameLocal` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
For Each p In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
    If p.Style = wdStyleHeading1 Then
        p.Style = wdStyleHeading1
    End If
Next p
```

That said, using Find/Replace is way faster than looping through all paragraphs.

Comment: But the problem with this is when I step through and inspect p.Style, it gives the value "Heading 1", and therefore will never match wdStyleHeading1, which has a numeric value. How can I find/replace a formatting style?

Comment: @xvpnkr - “How can I find/replace a formatting style?” If you don’t know how to use Find/Replace see https://www.howtogeek.com/363203/how-to-find-and-replace-formatting-in-microsoft-word/

Comment: Thanks for the tip Timothy. Recording the macro to see how it is done references "Heading 1" again, so I can merge the 2 solutions together.

Comment: «But the problem with this is when I step through and inspect p.Style, it gives the value "Heading 1", and therefore will never match wdStyleHeading1, which has a numeric value» You're missing the point that wdStyleHeading1 = "Heading 1" in English, "Titre 1" in French, and so on. I could just as easily have used -2 instead of wdStyleHeading1.

Comment: Of course, if p.Style would give the same value, but it does not. If p.Style = -2 will never be true if p.Style gives the string local name of the style applied, rather than the enumeration.

Comment: If on an English-language system you open a document created on, say, a French-language system, with the built-in Heading Styles 'Titre 1', 'Titre 2', 'Titre 3', etc., those same Heading Styles should display as 'Heading 1', 'Heading 2', 'Heading 2', etc. That's because, behind the scenes, Word uses the enumerated constants - 2 through -10 and translates them into whatever language the current system uses. Hence, your VBA code should be able to work with the enumeration. Indeed, that is the only reason SpaceFlex's ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal code works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your style definitions are correct in the attached template, you don't even need a macro for this. All you need do is check the 'automatically update document styles' option, found under Developer|Document Template>Templates. With that set, all you need do is save, close, then re-open the document.

Otherwise, using Find/Replace for all 9 Heading Styles:

```
Sub SetHeadingLanguage()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  'Style enumerations run from -2 (wdStyleHeading1) to -10 (wdStyleHeading9)
  For i = -2 To -10 Step -1
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Style = i
      .Replacement.Style = i
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done."
End Sub
```